# How to change the color of part of a text in LAtex?

Tags: typography, tools

How to change the color of part of text in LAtex?

I am going to write a sentence with bold blue color at somewhere in my context. But don't know how to change the color.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can use `xcolor` package for this. Use `textcolor` micro for coloring your text.

`\usepackage{xcolor}
\textcolor{color}{text}`

You can use color names like `red`, `blue` etc. For more information please refer to [color section](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Colors) in [Latex Wikibook](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX).

Comment: Sometimes, I have observed that color of the text extends beyond the {text}. What I mean that the "Sample textx and other texts followed by {text}" are also colored. Do not know why this happens. One workaround I have figured out is {\color{color}{text}}.